# How to get angularjs variable value to other .js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I want to get angularjs variable to other js file. My angular js file code is...

```
  angular.module('myApp.menu', ['myApp.cloverApi', 'myApp.preOperation'])
    .controller('popMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',  'category', 'order', 'init', 'mInfoService', 'preop', 'mobileDetector', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, category, order, init, mInfoService, preop, mobileDetector) {
 mInfoService.init($scope.errorCallback)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.merchant.shopName = $scope.capitalizing(data.name);
```

I want to get merchant.shopName to other js file so how can i get this variable value.
and my html file code.

```
 <span ng-show="!isMerchant">{{merchant.shopName}}</span>
```

I want to catch this variable in script file as below

```
<script>
addToHomescreen({
    message: 'Add {{merchant.shopName}} to Your Phone, tap %icon, then <strong>Add to Home Screen </strog>',
    displayPace: 0
    });
</script>
```

but is not working

Comment: Using Angular, it's very uncommon to see anything in <script> tags like this. Instead, using factories to hold data that gets communicated through html via scopes is standard procedure, i think.

Where is merchant.shopName being generated from and where do you want it to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever data you wanna use through out your application than you must use [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

In your case:

```
angular.module('myApp.menu', ['myApp.cloverApi', 'myApp.preOperation'])
.controller('popMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',  'category', 'order',     'init', 'mInfoService', 'preop', 'mobileDetector', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, category, order, init, mInfoService, preop, mobileDetector) {
mInfoService.init($scope.errorCallback)
            .success(function (data) {
                // Here is the change
                $rootScope.merchant.shopName = $scope.capitalizing(data.name);
```

and then in your html

```
<span ng-show="!$rootScope.isMerchant">{{$rootScope.merchant.shopName}}</span>
```

Comment: You must use $rootScope? that is the most unconstructive answer I've seen in SO, what about angular.factory? Why do you bind unnecessary data to the $rootScope? What if he doesn't need it through ALL of his files? -1.

Comment: it's ironically chuckle-able that above takes offence to the use of 'must,' only to follow with 'most' :) anyway, @CrazyGeek 's solution is one of many valid ways to do this, however should explain the caveats.

Answer (score 5):

This a good use-case for an angular service.

In another file, you create a service like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('factoryName', function(){
// create factory object
    var data = {};
    data.someProperty = 'Some Property';
    data.someMethod = function(){
        console.log('Service Method');
    }
// return the factory object
    return data;
})
```

Now that you have created your 'factoryName' service, inject it into a controller and scope it for your view.

```
angular.module('app').controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, factoryName){
    $scope.fromService = factoryName;
});
```

You're just about done. You'll of course need to reference the .js file in your index.html and finally use it in your html template, for example:

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
    <input ng-model="fromService.someProperty"/>
    <button ng-click="fromService.someMethod()">Console Log</button>
</div>
```

Please let me know if you'd like a Plnkr example.